# sending array to php via ajax json

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to send an array to php via Ajax Json, but i cant do it, when i send it all  i get on my server side is a csv string,

here is my jquery code where i create my array

```
$('#guardar_curso').click(function(){
    var respuestas = new Array();

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;

    var last_hidden = $('body').find('input[type="hidden"]').filter(':last');
    last_hidden = parseInt(last_hidden.val()) + 1;
    var count = 0;
    for(var a = 0; a<last_hidden; a++){
        for(var b = 0; b<4; b++){

            c = $('body').find('input[name="resp['+ a +']['+ b +']"]').val();
                if(c == ''){
                    respuestas[count] = c; //ignore this

                }else{
                    respuestas[count] = c; 
                }
            count++;
            }
        }
```

and this next is my jquery code where is my Ajax call triggered from a submit button:

```
                $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:CI.base_url + 'admin/guardar_curso',
                        data: curso_data + '&respuestas=' + respuestas,
                        dataType:"json",
                        success:function(response){
                            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                                salida = salida + value + "\n";
                            })
```

curso_data is my serialized data and "respuestas" is my array

it's just part of my code, i hope it helps make my point

any help i can get plz, this has been driving me nuts for hours, i want to loop that array with a foreach loop in php, thanks...

Comment: for me you are sending the "data" parameter in a wrong way. You should use Json syntax for that:

data: {curso_data: respuestas},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tring to concatenate an array and text which doesn't work. You could send the array as a JSON string, and decode it when it is received.

```
data: curso_data + '&respuestas=' + JSON.stringify(respuestas),
```

Then in php:

```
 /* convert json to php array*/
$respuestas= json_decode($_POST['respuestas']);
```

A simple test in php is  `print_r( $respuestas)` and look at the returned array in browser console

Comment: this worked, thanks a ton, i had tried stringify function but in a wrong way, your answer worked as a charm! thanks again!!